# Laravel with POSTGRESS . You might need to add an explicit type cast error, operator does not exist:

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql

I switched my database from Mysql to Postgress and now I'm getting the above error after switching.

My function looks like this.

```
public function viewRunDetails(Run_List $id) {
    $this->viewRun = $id->id;
    $profile = Profile::where('id', $id->profile_id)->first();
    $runnerlist = Runners_List::where('run_list_id', $id->id)->get();
    $pace = $runnerlist->sum('distance');
    $TotalPace = Runners_List::where('run_list_id', $id->id)->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( 
        TIME_TO_SEC( `pace` ) ) / ?) as total', [$pace])->first();
    $variable = substr($TotalPace->total, 0, strpos($TotalPace->total, "."));
}
```

distance is in the decimal format while the pace is in time format.

Specifically, I'm getting the error here

```
$TotalPace = Runners_List::where('run_list_id', $id->id)->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( 
        TIME_TO_SEC( `pace` ) ) / ?) as total', [$pace])->first();
```

Any ideas why it's showing that error? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Martin. Can you please provide the full error trace provided for you in the terminal? There may be information helping us answer you better.

Comment: hi @WiGeeky

I've been googling and found that it's because of this sec_to_time in SQL is different with POSTGRES

Comment: Consider adding the error to your main post as well, although I think there's already an edit for that.

Comment: You can post your own answer to your question so that anyone with the same question can figure out what they need to do later. Happy Coding!